# Canceling an asynchronous socket operation

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, multicast

I have a C# .Net 3.5 application that sends a multicast "Hello" packet to whomever may be subscribed to a particular multicast group and then listens for all the responses. So, every X seconds, I may send a "Hello" packet and make a note of everybody who responds.

It is intended to be used like this:

```
MulticastHello hello_ = new MulticastHello();

// alert our UI of any responses to the 'Hello'
hello_.ReceivedHelloResponse += OnHelloResponse;

// this timer function is triggered every X seconds
private void OnTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // stop listening for responses to the last 'hello'
    hello_.CancelHello();

    // send a new 'hello' and start listening for responses
    hello_.SendHello("224.0.100.1");
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm having issues canceling the asynchronous read. My `private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)` function will occasionally throw a `System.ArgumentException` that says "The IAsyncResult object was not returned from the corresponding asynchronous method on this class."

How can I reliably cancel an asynchronous socket operation. Or, is there a better way of doing this?

My implementation is below.

Thanks,
PaulH

```
public class HelloResponseEventArgs : EventArgs { /*...*/ }

public class MulticastHello : IDisposable
{
    public event EventHandler<HelloResponseEventArgs> ReceivedHelloResponse;

    private Socket socket_;

    private byte[] received_ = new byte[HelloResponse.Size];

    private EndPoint responder_ = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

    protected virtual void OnReceivedHelloResponse(HelloResponseEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<HelloResponseEventArgs> evt = ReceivedHelloResponse;
        if (null != evt)
            evt(this, e);
    }

    private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        IPEndPoint ipendpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        EndPoint endpoint = ipendpoint as EndPoint;

        try
        {
            socket_.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref endpoint);
        }
        catch (System.ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            // the read was canceled. This is expected.
            return;
        }

        // decode the response and set the event
        IPEndPoint remote = endpoint as IPEndPoint;
        HelloResponse response = new HelloResponse(Deserialize<HelloPacket>(received_));
        OnReceivedHelloResponse(new HelloResponseEventArgs(remote.Address.ToString(), response));

        // keep receiving responses until canceled
        socket_.BeginReceiveFrom(received_,
            0,
            received_.Length,
            SocketFlags.None,
            ref endpoint,
            new AsyncCallback(OnReceive),
            null);
    }

    // stop listening for responses to the hello frame
    public void CancelHello()
    {
        if (socket_ != null)
            socket_.Close();
    }

    // send an initial 'Hello' to the a multicast address. Start listening for responses
    public void SendHello(string address)
    {
        socket_ = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        socket_.MulticastLoopback = false;
        socket_.Ttl = 255;

        HelloResponse send = new HelloResponse();
        byte[] data = Serialize(send.Packet);

        EndPoint remote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(address), 7);
        socket_.SendTo(data, remote);

        socket_.BeginReceiveFrom(received_,
            0,
            received_.Length,
            SocketFlags.None,
            ref responder_,
            new AsyncCallback(OnReceive),
            null);
    }

    #region IDisposable Members
    /* close the socket on dispose*/
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Close()` doesn't wait. It exits immediately. So, if the next SendHello() comes before EndReceiveFrom() finishes it will throw the `System.ArgumentException`.

The solution is to wait on an event object after the `Close()` call that is set when the `System.ObjectDisposedException` is caught in `OnReceive`.

-PaulH

Answer (score 3):

Send the socket as the state arg in BeginReceive. I.e.

```
socket_.BeginReceiveFrom(
         received_,
         0,
         received_.Length,
         SocketFlags.None,
         ref endpoint,
         new AsyncCallback(OnReceive),
         socket_);
```

Then in OnReceive use that instead of the class variable socket. I.e.

```
Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
socket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref endpoint);
```

This ensures the EndReceiveFrom call is happening on the same socket that the BeginReceive was called on. Then as PaulH mentions just catch the ObjectDisposedException in OnReceive which will be the signal that Close() was called on the socket.

-Oli